# Algorithmic gap for Hochbaum's (greedy) algorithm for (metric) uncapacitated facility location

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization, error-bounds, facility-location, algorithms

In [Jain *et al.* (2003)](http://pages.cs.aueb.gr/~markakis/research/jacm03-facloc.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, at the bottom of page 801, they construct an instance of (metric) uncapacitated facility location for which they claim the greedy (Hochbaum's) algorithm has gap $\Omega\left(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right)$. The algorithm is as follows:

Construct an instance of set cover, where the ground set of elements is the set of clients $D$ and the set system contains all sets of the form $(i,A)$ where $i \in F$ is a facility and $A \subseteq D$ is a set of clients. Set $(i,A)$ covers the elements in $A$ and $\operatorname{cost}(i,A) = f_i + \sum{d_{ij}}$. The greedy algorithm is to choose the set $(i,A)$ that minimizes $\frac{\operatorname{cost}(i,A)}{|A\,\cap\, \text{uncovered}|}$. This can be done in polytime by iterating through the facilities $i \in F$ and through $s = 1,\ldots,|\text{uncovered}|$ and considering $A$ to be the $s$ closest uncovered clients to facility $i$.

Part of the proof of Jain *et al.*<sup>1</sup> is to claim that (on the instance they construct) the above greedy algorithm will open all $k$ facilities, while the optimal thing to do is to open only one of the facilities. **I can't seem to see why the greedy algorithm will open all facilities.** I can see how this would be the case if the cost of each element in set $S_i$ is $\sum\limits_{j=1}^ip^{j-1}$, but in this case opening one facility will have cost $$p^k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}p^{k-i+1}\sum_{j=1}^ip^{j-1} = \Theta(kp^k),$$ while they claim that the optimal cost (that of opening one facility) is $$p^k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^ip^{j-1} = \Theta(p^k).$$ A central part of their proof seems to be that since the greedy algorithm described above will open all $k$ facilities, it will have cost $\Omega(kp^k)$ and therefore, the gap between the algorithms performance and the optimum is $\Omega(k)$. Since there are $n = \Theta(p^k)$ clients, $k = \log_p n = \ln n/\ln p$, and therefore for $p = \ln n$, we have that the gap is $\Omega\left(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right)$.

**Another question I have is that for $p = O(1)$, wouldn't this result in a gap of $\Omega(\log n)$ which is a stronger result? Why doesn't this work?** The last sentence of their paragraph is "We do not know whether the approximation factor of Hochbaum’s algorithm on metric instances is strictly less than $\log n$." So I assume I'm missing something.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Jain, K., Mahdian, M., Markakis, E. *et al.* (2003). Greedy Facility Location Algorithms Analyzed Using Dual Fitting with Factor-Revealing LP. *Journal of the ACM.* **50(6)**:795–824.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I'm looking at the algorithm as it's described in [Hochbaum (1982)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01581035), which works like this: Suppose we have enumerated all $2^n-1$ subsets of the customers. Subset $P_m$ has cost 
$$C_m = \min_{j\in J} \left(\sum_{i\in P_m} c_{ij} + f_j\right),$$
i.e., the fixed plus transportation cost if we choose the best facility for the set $P_m$ of customers. At each iteration, we choose the $P_k$ that maximizes the ratio
$$\frac{|P_m|}{C_m},$$
open the best facility for that $P_k$, remove the customers in $P_k$ from all of the other $P_m$ sets, and repeat.

I'm not exactly sure how that translates to the algorithm described in Jain et al. (2003); they say the two algorithms are equivalent, so let's take their word for it.

Their example has $k$ facilities with a fixed cost of $p^k$ for some $p$, all located at the same spot. (They don't give any restrictions on $p$ but the example only makes sense if $p$ is a positive integer.) There are $k-1$ groups of customers, called $S_1,\ldots,S_{k-1}$, oriented as rings around the facilities. $S_i$ contains $p^{k-i+1}$ customers, each at a distance of $\sum_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}$ from the facilities.

Consider the first iteration of Hochbaum's algorithm. Suppose $P_1=S_1$, $P_2=S_2$, and $P_{1,2}=S_1\cup S_2$. The relevant ratios are:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{|P_1|}{C_1} & = \frac{p^k}{p^k+p^kp^0} = \frac12 \\
\frac{|P_2|}{C_2} & = \frac{p^{k-1}}{p^k + p^{k-1}(p^0+p^1)} = \frac{1}{2p+1} < \frac12 \\
\frac{|P_{1,2}|}{C_{1,2}} & = \frac{p^k+p^{k-1}}{p^k + p^kp^0 + p^{k-1}(p^0+p^1)} = \frac{p+1}{3p+1} < \frac12.
\end{align}$$
And presumably the pattern will repeat, in the sense that if we either add more "rings" to the subset, or we replace $S_1$ with a different "ring", the ratio will go down. Therefore, $P_1 = S_1$ attains the maximum ratio, so we open a facility (doesn't matter which one) and assign $S_1$ to it. Then remove $S_1$ from all of the other subsets, and repeat. The same logic will hold at the next iteration, so we will open a facility and assign $S_2$ to it, and so on. This continues until we have opened all $k$ facilities.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood them as saying the sum of the distances of the clients in group $S_i$ from the facilities was $\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}$, but actually each client in group $S_i$ has distance $\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}$ from the facilities. This makes sense, thanks for the clear and concise response.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Comment: Also to clarify the relationship b/w the above greedy method to the algorithm described in Jain et. al (2003)—referring to Algorithm 1 from the paper—they are actually not equivalent. They differ in that Alg. 1 no longer accounts for the fixed cost $f_i$ in measuring the effectiveness of covering subset $P_m$ with facility $j$, i.e. $|P_m|/\sum_{i \in P_m} c_{ij}$, if that facility has already been chosen by the algorithm. Their algorithm is able to achieve a constant-factor approximation for metric uncapacitated facility location, while the above greedy procedure is not.

Comment: I was referring to where it says that Hochbaum’s greedy algorithm for facility location is equivalent to the set cover algorithm applied on the set of stars. Maybe I misunderstood that point though.

Comment: Actually after looking again at the Jain et. al (2003) paper, they do say that the optimum solution, opening just one facility, has value $p^k + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}$. So I believe the sum of the distances of the clients in group $S_i$ from the facilities is $\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}$ (i.e. $d(s) = \frac{1}{p^{k-i+1}}\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}$ for all $s \in S_i$ where $d(a)$ is the distance of client $a$ from the facilities).

Comment: Note the above would make $$\frac{|P_1|}{C_1} = \frac{p^k}{p^k + p^0},\quad\frac{|P_2|}{C_2} = \frac{p^{k-1}}{p^k + p^0 + p^1},\quad\frac{|P_{1,2}|}{C_{1,2}} = \frac{p^k + p^{k-1}}{p^k + 2p^0 + p^1},$$ and therefore $\frac{|P_{1,2}|}{C_{1,2}} > \frac{|P_1|}{C_1}$ for $p,k$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Hmm. You might be right. Have you tried to prove their claim that "with careful choice of $k$, the ratio of these two expressions is $\Omega(\log n/\log\log n)$, for either "my" definition of the cost or "yours"?

Comment: Yeah. Using your def. of cost, choosing one facility has cost $p^k+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}p^{k-i+1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p^{j-1}=\Theta(kp^k)$ and using my def. of cost, choosing one facility has cost $p^k+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^ip^{j-1}=\Theta(p^k)$. Comparing this to the cost of the greedy algorithm (which is claimed to be $\Theta(kp^k)$, since all facilities are chosen), "my" gives gap $\Omega(k)$ and "yours" gives gap $\Theta(1)$. Then, since number of clients, denote $n = \Theta(p^k)$, $k = \log_p n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln p}$, so for $p = \ln n$, the gap is $\ln n/\ln \ln n$

Comment: Another question I do have, though, is that setting $p = O(1)$ in the above analysis gives a $\log n$ gap, which is a stronger result. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: OK. I will need to think some more about why greedy would open all facilities. Possibly it's just an error in the paper, but hopefully I can salvage my answer. Regarding the stronger result, I couldn't speculate, although maybe they were just trying to show that Hochbaum's algorithm is inferior in the worst case and didn't care "how" inferior.